# Netbeans on Mac OS X: Where are Apache Tomcat Old Logs?

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, netbeans

I have installed `NetBeans 8.1` on OS X with Apache tomcat 8.

All the time I run my web application, the logs show me old error messages, and this is very confusing. 
So I need to clear the logs of tomcat, where are those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location in the default installation is at

`/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/8.1/apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base/logs`

This is an [old known bug marked as `WONTFIX`](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198452)